# Angularjs HTTP service POST progress event

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Since most topics about this subject are over a year old, I asked myself if there are **any good solutions to track an ajax progress event from an http service** (for a loading bar or to track how many bytes it has downloaded). Without the use of 3rd parties :)

these events:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.addEventListener("progress")
ajax.addEventListener("load")
ajax.addEventListener("error")
ajax.addEventListener("abort")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "there are any good solutions to track an ajax progress event from an http service"

Answer (score 2):

I've made something like that using a promise with notify for the progress :

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("Filename", file.name);
fd.append("file", file);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
      deferred.notify(event);
}, false);

xhr.addEventListener("load", function (data) {
     deferred.resolve(event.target.response);
}, false);

xhr.addEventListener("error", function (data) {
     deferred.reject(event.target.response);
}, false);

xhr.addEventListener("abort", function (data) {
     deferred.reject(event.target.response);
}, false);

xhr.open("POST", URL);
xhr.send(fd);

return deferred.promise;
```