# Angular factory: update scope with progress during upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, angularjs-scope, factory

I've written an Angular factory which handles uploads to S3:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.s3', [])
    .factory('S3', function ($q) {
        var aws = { ... }

        var progress = 0;

        function getFileName(fileURI) {
            return fileURI.split('/').pop();
        }

        return {
            progress: progress,
            upload: function (fileKey, fileURI, mimeType) {
                var fileName = getFileName(fileURI);
                if (fileName === '') {
                    console.log('File name can\'t be empty');
                    return;
                }

                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.promise.then(function (event) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(event));
                    console.log(event);
                }, function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    console.log(error);
                });

                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                var fileUploadOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
                fileUploadOptions.fileKey = 'file';
                fileUploadOptions.fileName = fileName;
                fileUploadOptions.chunkedMode = false;
                fileUploadOptions.params = {
                    'key': fileKey,
                    'AWSAccessKeyId': aws.access_key_id,
                    'acl': aws.acl,
                    'policy': aws.policy,
                    'signature': aws.signature
                };

                fileTransfer.upload(fileURI, encodeURI('https://' + aws.bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'),
                    defer.resolve, defer.reject, fileUploadOptions);
                fileTransfer.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {
                    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                        progress = (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100;
                        console.log(progress);
                    } else {
                        //loadingStatus.increment();
                    }
                };

                return defer.promise();
            }
        };
    });
```

This code works fine and the file is uploaded to S3. The progress log is also working. When I use this factory in a controller, and bind progress to the scope, I don't see the progress updates in my scope. I guess it's due to the fact that the scope does not get an update event.

I've seen a workaround where the factory is initialized with the scope, and scope.apply() is called within the factory. I don't think this is the right way to do this in Angular, but I don't know the right way either. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dmitry Tolmachov answer would definitly work but I would have used the defer.notify because you are already using a promise and because using the notify you do not need to manually call the digest cycle :

```
fileTransfer.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        progress = (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100;
        console.log(progress);
        defer.notify(progress);
    } else {
        //loadingStatus.increment();
    }
};
```

And then use it in your controler were .then(sucess,error,notify)

cf : [Angularjs HTTP service POST progress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097978/angularjs-http-service-post-progress-event/32098213#32098213)

Comment: Yes! I just discovered this is possible to, and I think it's even better! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that when fileTransfer.onprogress is called, it does not start digest cycle. I highly recommend this article for reading: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

As for solution, one of the simple ways will be:

1) Inject $rootScope into factory:

```
.factory('S3', function ($q, $rootScope) {
```

2) Start digest cycle manually:

```
progress = (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100;
                    console.log(progress);
$rootScope.$digest();
```

This must fix it.

Comment: Thanks! This works as expected! But shouldn't I call $apply() instead? In the article you provided, only the $apply() function is called explicitly.

Comment: For rootScope it does not matter if you look at official documentation for scope.apply you will see that:

     function $apply(expr) {
       try {
         return $eval(expr);
       } catch (e) {
         $exceptionHandler(e);
       } finally {
         $root.$digest();
       }
    }
So $rootScope.$digest is called anyway, but the purpose of $apply is to run some code and run digest after it

Comment: For ordinary $scope however it do matter, as $scope.$digest() will update view and run watchers only for this $scope. When running $scope.$apply() will update the whole application as usual